# How to get mysql back up tables starting with specific letter?

Tags: phpmyadmin, backup, mysql, database-backups

I have bulk data of 2 gb on mysql server and I want to get backup of it.

I tried using `mysqldump -u root newspress > /tmp/newspress.sql`

But to download from server to my local machine it take very long time. So I want to get specific tables in database that `starts with J`.

Forexample: `Jobseeker, Jobs, Joncategory...` etc

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shell script will select all tables starting with 'm' and dump them to the current directory in a file called  `database.table.sql` (for example: test.employees.sql):

```
DB="test"
TABLES=`mysql -uroot -BN -e "SHOW TABLES FROM $DB LIKE 'm%'"`
for TABLE in $TABLES;
do
   mysqldump -uroot $DB $TABLE > $DB.$TABLE.sql;
done
```

Note that to reduce the size of the backup produced by `mysqldump`, you can compress it:

```
shell> mysqldump -u root newspress > /tmp/newspress.sql
shell> gzip /tmp/newspress.sql
```

A 2Gb dump will be reduced to quite a smaller size.

Comment: it is giving error 

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I used mysql -u root -p****

Comment: @NaanuManu That's a total different problem, but make sure there is no space between -p and your password. The above script was tested. Please also see my note about compressing the backup, that might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

download   [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). then you can easy take backup in a single click. it is so fast.

Comment: Database is on linux server and i can access mysql via command prompt only.

Comment: ok ... but wb is available for linux also. please see the site that i mentioned above

Comment: Yes dude.. I looked into it. I cannot install user interface on server and access for my system...

Comment: so sorry ma brother i never used linux